# Convert unicode string to array of bytes

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using OpenGL and I need to pass to a function array of bytes.

```
glCallLists(len('text'), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTES, 'text');
```

This way it's working fine. But I need to pass unicode text. I think that it should work like this:

```
text = u'unicode text'
glCallLists(len(text), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, convert_to_array_of_words(text));
```

Here I use `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` that says I'll give array where each element takes 2 bytes, and somehow convert unicode text to array of words.

So, how can I convert unicode string to "raw" array of chars' numbers?

Comment: I don't think any conversion will be necessary. Unicode text should already be an array of unsigned shorts

Comment: @John: Depends on whether the library is built to use UCS-2 or UCS-4.

Comment: Yes, probably, but I get this error when trying to pass unicode string: `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: No array-type handler for type <type 'unicode'> (value: u'\u0439') registered`

Comment: @Ignacio: how is a string literal in his code a library issue? Do you mean the OpenGL? library

Comment: @John: No, I mean the Python library.

Comment: @Ignacio: Ok, didn't know that recompiling python was an option. good to know.

Comment: @John: You can build Python passing either `--enable-unicode=ucs2` or `--enable-unicode=ucs4` to `configure` in order to control the internal storage format of unicode strings. Note that C modules must have been built against a version of Python that has the same setting as yours or they will not be able to load.

Comment: Just a comment: Unicode test is not an array of unsigned shorts in Python, it's an object. When itered over it gives unicode characters, not unsigned shorts. The internal representation is as mentioned UCS-2 or UCS-4, but that doesn't mean it "is" unsigned shorts in any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UTF encoding that takes up 2 bytes per character is UTF-16:

```
print repr(u'あいうえお'.encode('utf-16be'))
print repr(u'あいうえお'.encode('utf-16le'))
```

Comment: Yes they can. However, it was inaccurate for me to say that it uses 2 bytes per character. Some will take up 4 bytes, being composed of a "surrogate pair".

Comment: @Mike: I think you mean to say not all code points can be represented in UCS-2.